# React Native Router Flux dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

In my React Native project I have an import:

```
import { Actions as NavigationActions } from 'react-native-router-flux'
```

I also have a prop type for a route of `this.props.route` which equates to 'someRoute'. I would like to use the two together effectively like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={NavigationActions.this.props.route}>
```

Obviously that doesn't work but how can use the two together?

I've tried

```
const { route } = this.props
<TouchableOpacity onPress={NavigationActions.route}>
```

and also

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={{$NavigationActions}.${route}}>
```

but neither work. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What do you mean by combining two props? Is `NavigationActions.this.props.route` a function?

Comment: Yes it triggers a route change. I'm using https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [react-native-router-flux minitutorial](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/MINI_TUTORIAL.md).

You aren't  meant to access their `props`.

```
<Router>
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="pageOne" component={PageOne} title="PageOne" initial={true} />
    <Scene key="pageTwo" component={PageTwo} title="PageTwo" />
  </Scene>
</Router>

<Text onPress={Actions.pageTwo}>This is PageOne!</Text>
```

**Edit:**

Since you are looking forward dynamic redirection, the approach is the same as if you were dealing with objects.

`a = { foo: 'bar' }` -> `a.foo` or `a['foo']` *(second being the dynamic version)*

That is `Action[page]` in your case.

Which becomes

```
const route = this.props.route;
<TouchableOpacity onPress={NavigationActions[route]}>
```

Make sure that route is actually the `key` that the `Scene` has.

Comment: I'm using the Ignite starter for React Native. Here's an example of a working route created by them `<RoundedButton onPress={NavigationActions.login}>` same implementation I just want to make the route name dynamic. My routes are setup as you show above. `<Scene key='login' component={LoginScreen} title='Login' hideNavBar />`

Comment: @mtwallet if it's dynamic you should be able to do `Actions['page']` instead

Comment: @zurfx if I `console.log` this.props.route I can see the route name, if I log `NavigationAction` I can see the Actions object but if I combine the two and log `NavigationActions[route]` I get undefined? I have the routes setup correctly in RNRF.

Comment: @mtwallet make sure that `NavigationActions[route]` is pointing to the desired `key` component.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this `NavigationActions[this.props.route]` if your router have a `scene` with the value `this.props.route`

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={NavigationActions[this.props.route]}>
```

If this doesn't work check the `Router` you defined whether it have a `scene` with `key` have the value of `this.props.route`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
const route = this.props.route;
Actions[route]()
```